# Need to c++ functions like handlemessage function for single or multi-radio wireless node interface

Tags: omnet++

In interface element level of wireless nodes:
I know handleMessage() is called by the simulation kernel when the module receives a message.
Is there a similar function when a physical wireless link is established between two single or multi-radio nodes to communicate them is called? If there is no such function, how can I generate it?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. Could you precise: 1) what type of wireless node you consider, 2) what you mean by _link is established_ 3) what is _custom function_?

Comment: According to Jerzy D.'s comment, I made the question more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as *physical wireless link*. Radios transmit packets that may or may not be received on the other end. That *physical wireless link* is just an abstraction layered on top of the low level communication.

I.e. when do you consider a *physical wireless link* present? When data was exchanged between the two peer? Only one way or data should travel in both ways? How will *node1* know that *node2* received the sent data? Should it wait for acknowledgement? For how long? What is if the acknowledgement is lost during the transmission. And so on...

Providing reliable communication channel between two nodes is the responsibility of the Link Layer (or Mac layer if you want to call it that way like in `Ieee80211Mac`). So you should add your logic somewhere there, however you must define your own logic. Take a look at the  `handleLowerPacket()` as a good place to insert your code.

Comment: Dear @Rudi, I confirm your comment about the physical wireless link that is an abstract concept, not a physical thing. I mean when two nodes are in the communication range of each other and SNIR be greater than the receiver threshold and select a channel to provide communication. And about my question, I want to find which radio interface is received message or packet in handlemessage function or create a new function similar to handlemessage function for firing an event when an interface receives a message or packet.

Comment: Even in the scenario you just described, transmitting data is a stochastic process.  There is no such thing as 'communication range' there is just a certain probability for a given distance that a transmitted packet will be received successfully. That depends still on a lot of other factors: modulation type, error correction, fading, antenna characteristics, interference etc.). At physical level, saying that the communication range is X meter, is just an arbitrary value. A meaningful definition would be: the range where the packet loss ratio raises above 5% (or some arbitrary value).

Comment: At the end of the day, this leads to the question: At what abstraction level you want to simulate the world. If you are interested in cross interference between radios, then you should go for simulating WiFi cards with detailed (dimensional) radio models. On the other hand, if you are interested in the behavior of some routing protocol that runs on the nodes, you don't really care about the low level packet transmission details. In that case you better go with a more simple radio model like the `UnitDiskRadio`. In that case you can set the various communication ranges as a parameter.